# send xml body using webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

Please tell me how to send xml body to web service please show an example.. i would be thank full to you please.....

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache:false,
    async: false,
    data:{}            //xml data send to webservice 
    url:"webservice/HelloWorld",
    dataType :"xml",
    contentType:"text/xml",
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //show XML Data
    var xmlData =$j(data).find('HelloWorldResult').text();
    alert(xmlData);
});
```

Comment: @Lakshmana please do not change code! The `j` is there for a reason, to prevent conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard  Sorry boss i thought `$` is simply enough.

Comment: @LakshmanaKumar it's the common usage, but not the only one. Please don't remove things you don't know, especially when part of code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, what is your send type and return type? And why XML and not JSON?

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache:false,
    async: false,
    data:{"xml" : var_xml}             
    url:"webservice/HelloWorld",
    dataType :"xml",
    contentType:"text/xml",
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //show XML Data
    var xmlData =$j(data).find('HelloWorldResult').text();
    alert(xmlData);

});
```

There you send a variable called `var_xml`, in PHP access it with $_POST['xml] and you can return an XML to use in JS.

Though this is very bad practice, rather use json.

Comment: .asmx of microsoft .net because i have webservice which return xml

Comment: Ok fair enough, just remember that JS can't do cross domain calls... but for that it should be fine, generate your `var_xml` and handle the return in .NET haven't done it in a while but should be something like this: `string theXml = c.Request.Form["xml"];` and then you parse it to XML.

Answer (score 0):

If your Webservice is PHP, I would send the XML as a string - `data:"<xmlNode><child></child></xmlNode>"`  then parse it in PHP with something like [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the xml as a string in the body of the request,but you have to use the XMLHttpRequest object. All the details are in David Flanagan's book JavaScript The Definitive Guide.

An excerpt from the book with an example on how to do it can be found on the following link,

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/definitive4/index.html

I hope it helps.

Thanks.